# WebRTC - Recording audio stream into file from within C++ application

Tags: javascript, c++, webrtc, rtp

I am playing around with WebRTC's "..\trunk\talk\examples\peerconnection" sample.

I have modified "..\peerconnection\server\server_test.html" so it streams audio to "peerconnection_client.exe".  This is working fine and the following function:

```
int32_t Channel::ReceivedRTPPacket(const int8_t* data, int32_t length, const PacketTime& packet_time)
```

shows incoming RTP packets sent from Chrome.

How can I save this RTP packet stream into a file (.pcm format?) from within the receiving side?

Comment: are you open to using another library like `Gstreamer`? You should be able to push each new packet to a `appsrc` for gstreamer and work with the rtp stream that way.

Comment: @bwtrent Thanks for the response.  Problem is that I don't have direct access to the packets from peerconnection_client. These packets are somewhere deep down in the WebRTC stack and I haven't worked out how to access them.

Answer (score 3):

When you get the remote stream (OnStreamAdded) in your c++ application you can add an `AudioTrackSink` to the audio track and write raw PCM data.

Also see here: [Writing WebRTC (AudioTrackSinkInterface) raw audio to disc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426888/writing-webrtc-audiotracksinkinterface-raw-audio-to-disc)

(Yes, this question was old but the web lacks information about the native webrtc library so I wanted to add)